# How to reduce face/poly count for characters while keeping quads?

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I really hope this is possible, I've made some characters for a game but the face/poly count is way too high as in like 10 times too high, I have tried using the decimate tool to fix it but one it still leaves quite a lot of faces even if I put it to 0.1, two it makes it triangles instead of quads and it also makes it look very bad.

Is there any way to reduce the amount of faces my characters have by a huge amount without using the decimate tool?

Comment: have you tried an Un-Subdivide? shortcut ctrl E

Comment: I did but I'll be honest it's probably my fault because I'm new to making characters and Blender in general but even if I use that, it still has too many faces and some are still turned into triangles instead of quads, some even had something like 6 vertices.

Comment: You can detriangulate (alt J) and maybe share your file or at least a part of it

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, unfortunately even then it still has some triangles, I've made multiple characters but I'm starting to think I'm going to have to restart them all if I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" procedure is Retopology:

using both the "snap onto surfaces" function and/or the shrinkwrap modifier you will build a new mesh projecting vertices onto the charcter you already made.

In this way you can control the amount of vertices and distribuite them exactly where you need them, following good edgeflows and avoiding triangles and N-gons.

If the new LoPoly character still misses some important details you can bake a normal map using the "selected to active" function, so that the missing details will be reproduced by the heghts illusion of the normal map texture.

[image]